# Running Java in while loop shell

Tags: java, shell, command-line, batch-file

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (plugins.txt) do (
echo %%a
java -cp .;svnkit.jar Test %%a

cd %dotcms_home%

call ant deploy-plugins > test1.txt

FindStr "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" test1.txt

del "test1.txt"

cd C:\dotCMSResults
echo Errorlevel: %ERRORLEVEL%
if %ERRORLEVEL% ==1 (echo ^<tr BGCOLOR=\"#FF0000\"^>^<td^>Build^</td^>^<td^>Fout\!^</td^>^</tr^> >> goedje.html ) else (echo ^<tr BGCOLOR=\"#00FF00\"^>^<td^>Build^</td^>^<td^>Gelukt\!^</td^>^</tr^> >> goedje.html) 
cd %dotcms_home%
call ant undeploy-plugins > test.txt
)
```

Hello, I want to run a Java class in commandline in a while loop. I searched on Google and found a way to do it. But now he is only doing it the first time, the second and third time he said:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Test.  Program will exit.
```

I don't know why, esspecialy because he is running the first time correct. Only the second and third time he is going in the loop he gets this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most probably due to your `cd` statements - you must be changing away from the current directory which contains the `svnkit.jar` (or a `Test.class`?) so that it can't find Test class anymore on the second loop.

To fix that add `cd` to the correct directory before calling `java`.

Or, which is better, use absolute paths as a java classpath argument, i.e.

`java -cp c:/folder1;c:/folder2/svnkit.jar`.

Comment: Agreed, this is the most likely cause. The error you're getting simply means that the JVM can't find the `Test` class you specified when starting the JVM.

Comment: Hmm.. This still not works, but I think I did something wrong:     java -cp .;"C:\dotCMS Automatic Install\svnkit.jar" "C:\dotCMS Automatic Install\Test" %%a

Comment: @Gynnad instead of "C:\dotCMS Automatic Install\Test" just put Test